# How to develop a timeline screen in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, hybrid-mobile-app

I am very new to building mobile apps and stuff.I am using react native to build a mobile app for a event and was wondering on how to design the timeline in react native.

I am attaching a sample image that would give you an idea .I will using an API to get the latest time line and it should reflect in the app.
[image]

Any help in pointing to right material or examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you elaborate? What do you mean integrate the schedule? What is the end goal? Currently, your question is too vague.

Comment: @kibar I updated the details .

Answer (score 4):

A timeline is basically just a list.
You could use a SectionList (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/sectionlist.html) where the header is the date, each item is the details of that day
So you would have something like that:

```
    <SectionList
      renderItem={({item}) => <ListItem title={item} />}
      renderSectionHeader={({section}) => <Header title={section.title} />}
      sections={[
        {data: [{title:"Weekly stand up", time:"2pm"},
{title:"Coffee", time:"10am"}], title: "Thursday, March 12"}
        {data: [{title:"Icons", time:"4pm"}], title: "Wednesday, March 11"}
      ]}
    />
```

Where ListItem is the detail of your day, Header is the date, and in sections you would have all the data

Comment: Thank you .I will give it a try with the above logic.